# jquery-ui autocomplete in textbox within a bootstrap modal does not populate clicked value into textbox

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My web app (rails 4 with turbolinks) uses bootstrap 3. I use jquery-ui-autocomplete to populate a textbox in a form within a bootstrap modal. If I use the keyboard to select an item from the list, the selected item gets populated in the textbox. But if I click on an item from the autocomplete dropdown, it does not get populated in the textbox.

Here is the view code and the script section:

```
<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#item_modal">
      Pick Item...
  </button>
</div>

 <div class="modal fade" id="item_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="item_modal_label">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="item_modal_label">Pick Item...</h4>
    </div>
    <%= form_tag '/items/do_something', method: :post do %>
      <div class="modal-body"  data-no-turbolink>
        <div>Start typing the name of the item</div> 
        <%= text_field_tag :source_item, nil, id: 'item-text-box', class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :source_item_id %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <%= submit_tag "Submit" class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
  var src_items = [];
  <% get_completion_items.each do |ci| %>
  src_items.push(
    {
      label: "<%= raw(ci.full_path) %>",
      id: "<%= ci.id %>"
    }
  );
  <% end %>
  $('#item-text-box').autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: src_items,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#source_item_id" ).val( ui.item.id );
      return false;
    }
  });
  </script>
```

## css

```
.ui-autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  float: left;
  display: none;
  min-width: 160px;
  _width: 160px;

  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;*border-right-width:2px;*border-bottom-width:2px
}
.ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item>a.ui-corner-all {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #555555;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.ui-widget-content li{
  padding-top: 0.25em;
  padding-bottom: 0.25em;
}

.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  background-image: none;
  padding-top: 0.25em;
  padding-bottom: 0.25em;
}
```

**Update:**

As requested by @Rooster in the comment below, I generated a bootply.

**Update2**:

Updated the bootply to add the actual css, and it works as expected in the bootply - still doesn't work in rails.

http://www.bootply.com/vo3xGdqxTX

**Update3**:
I removed all the autocomplete styling above from the rails view css and just kept the z-index. It still didn't work: (i.e, list shows, but clicking on an item does not fill the textbox).

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @Rooster I added a bootply link from the generated html - but in this case, the autocomplete dropdown doesn't even show the source items. Not sure what I am doing wrong here - in the actual rails app, it shows, but does not populate the clicked item into the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - the problem was that I was returning false in the select handler. I changed it to return true and it worked.

```
$('#item-text-box').autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: src_items,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#source_item_id" ).val( ui.item.id );
      return true; // this was false before, which caused the problem
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

i think syou've just got a css issue that is both hiding the autocomplete widget in the fiddle and preventing the autocomplete element from actually being clicked in your live code.  see this updated fiddle:  http://www.bootply.com/nRkKGhDKPo

try adding this css rule:

```
ul.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Comment: I updated my bootply with the css I am using - I already have a large z-index set for ui-autocomplete. It now works in the bootply, but does not work with the original rails code.

Comment: try inspecting one of the element in the ui-autocomplete and seeing what element pops up in console.  I somewhat suspect there is an invisible element over it or the zindex you set is being overriden.  You can also try tossing an important on that zindex rule to make sure its enforced.  Other than that, im not sure I can help more because the issue seems specific to your setup and is unreproducable.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Rooster - I tried adding !important to z-index, also saw that the right element is changing in the console when I inspect it. I don't know what else to try :-)

Comment: the only other thing I can think of, is that there is another script on the page stopping the propagation of the event.  thats hard to trace though....

Comment: or perhaps the wrong version of jquery is on the page?

Comment: I think you are right - the issue is likely the jquery version (I am having at least one other similar issue) - I am using two gems (among others) - that both require jquery. jquery-rails is using v 1.12.1 of jquery and ckeditor_rails does something to jquery (it has a jquery.js that modifies some jquery behavior for ckeditor to work). How do I track this down and fix the version of jquery?

Comment: Ok, figured it out - turns out it was nothing to do with jquery, etc. - I was returning false in the select handler, which was causing the selected link not to be populated. Fixed it. See my answer below. Thanks for all your help!